# How do I include the proper XML / HTML definitions in a file generated by XSL?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

As I understand it, you need to include the following code at the top of your HTML files to make sure they're parsed properly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
...
```

I'm generating an html file by transforming an XML file using an XSL file. This is going to be done using the MSXML tool, which produces a standard HTML file as output.

If I just do this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
...
```

Everything is fine. But if I do this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
...
```

I get the error `XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity` in Firefox, or `Cannot have a DOCTYPE declaration outside of a prolog.` in IE. Presumably this is because the parser is finding two `<?xml` definitions and getting confused.

How do I make the browser a) understand that I am using proper strict HTML, and b) make sure those declarations are put into the HTML output file that MSXML generates?

Answer (score 3):

The doctype can be controlled using the [xsl:output](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#output) element.

Comment: I think that works when I'm viewing the XML through XSL in a browser, but not when I run the MSXML "Generate HTML from these XML and XSL files" tool. :(

Comment: @Colen: no, xsl:output is part of the standard. It should "just work".

Comment: If it doesn't, then use a conforming XSLT processor.

Comment: Everything that I've found says that the MSXML stuff is "conforming", so I don't understand why this isn't working.

Comment: Just because Microsoft says that they're conforming, doesn't mean that they actually are.  After all, they've been claiming that Internet Explorer was standards compliant forever...